stm32f7xx+FreeRTOS+lwip - нет пинга
Продолжаю попытки запустить сеть на stm32(f767). Сделал проект (использовал это, как основу), подключил lwip, запустил. Прошел в отладчике - ethernet, похоже работает, на разъеме весело моргают светодиоды, в функции MX_LWIP_Inint вижу, что линк поднялся (соответствующий флаг есть). А вот дальше - непонятно. Пингую устройство снаружи - пинга нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что проверить или где искать. Заранее благодарен.
